# How to rewrite to nonexisting directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

On my webpage I've an Joomla Installation in `/joomla`, now I want to move the complete `/joomla` directory to `/` but old links with the `joomla` inside should be redericted to the new site at `/`. How is this possible?

In my `.htaccess` I've tried some stuff from somewhere out of the Internet, but the rules doesn't work, throws everytime an `404` HTTP Error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place this rule as your very first rule in `/joomla/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^ / [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Doesn't work if I place it into my .htaccess, no forward/rewrite happends.

Comment: Is it your first rule? What is location of your .htaccess? if you have .htaccess inside `/joomla/` then move it out.

Comment: Its the first and single rule (First line is a comment), its in the ``/`` directory.

Comment: Do you also have .htaccess inside `/joomla/` directory?

Comment: see update, remember it goes in `/joomla/.htaccess`.

Comment: Yes, the .htaccess of Joomla. When I rename it, it throws an ``404``.

Comment: Works really good, used it also at two or three more pages, but I'm using `RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^joomla(.*)? $1 [L,R=301]`, replace joomla with the dir which is gone :)